# Node js: error while identifying type of directory member

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to write a script that examines sub-directories and files of a given path. The problem is: when a sub-directory has multiple sub-directories there is an error. If there aren't multiple sub-directories the error doesn't appear. Does someone know why my code fails ?

Thank you for your help !

This:

```
const fs = require('fs');

class File
{
  constructor(fileName, directory)
  {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.directory = directory;
  }

  read()
  {
    return fs.readFileSync(this.directory.formatedPath(this.fileName), 'utf8', function(err, data)
    {
      if (err) throw err;
      return data.toString();
    });
  }

  write()
  {

  }
}

class Directory
{
  constructor(path, pathLevel = 0)
  {
    this.reveal(path, pathLevel);
    this.organizeMembers();
  }

  reveal(path, pathLevel)
  {
    this.path = path;
    this.pathLevel = pathLevel;
    this.directory = fs.readdirSync(this.path);
  }

  organizeMembers()
  {
    this.files = [], this.directories = [];
    for (var member of this.directory)
    {
      if (fs.lstatSync(member).isFile()) this.files.push(new File(member, this));
      if (fs.lstatSync(member).isDirectory())
      {
        this.directories.push(new Directory(this.formatedPath(member), this.pathLevel+1));
      }
    }
  }

  formatedPath(member)
  {
    if (this.path[this.path.length -1] !== '/') return this.path + '/' + member;
    return this.path + member;
  }

  createDirectory(path)
  {
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) fs.mkdirSync(path);
  }

}

var x = new Directory('./');

console.log(x);
```

produces this:

```
fs.js:958
  binding.lstat(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path));
          ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'Neuer Ordner 3'
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:958:11)
    at Directory.organizeMembers (/Users/mrb/Desktop/testFolder/nodePlayground.js:49:14)
    at new Directory (/Users/mrb/Desktop/testFolder/nodePlayground.js:32:10)
    at Directory.organizeMembers (/Users/mrb/Desktop/testFolder/nodePlayground.js:52:31)
    at new Directory (/Users/mrb/Desktop/testFolder/nodePlayground.js:32:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mrb/Desktop/testFolder/nodePlayground.js:70:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
```

But why ?

Comment: Hey Marco, I’m sorry for letting you wait for my answer. I had some personal issues these days... Thank you for your answer. The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `readdirSync` does not output the full path. So when you're listing the subdirectory files and using `lstatSync`, you're missing the subdirectory path, so that's why you're getting the error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'Neuer Ordner 3'`, because the file doesn't exist there.

All you have to do is use [path.join](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)

```
const path = require('path');

/* ... */

organizeMembers() {
  this.files = [], this.directories = [];
  for (var member of this.directory) {

    const filepath = path.join(this.path, member);

    // No need to use fs.lstat twice.
    const stat = fs.lstatSync(filepath);

    if (stat.isFile()) 
      this.files.push(new File(member, this));
    else if (stat.isDirectory())
      this.directories.push(new Directory(filepath, this.pathLevel + 1));
  }
}
```

Your `formatedPath` function can be removed in favour of `path.join`.